# Не могу создать дочернюю тему WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Делал все по [этой](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) инструкции, также смотрел [тут](https://misha.blog/wordpress/child-themes.html) и [тут](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html)
Вот что у меня в папке themes
[image: папка с темами]
Вот что у меня в `style.css` дочерней темы.
[image: style.css дочерней темы]
В ответ получаю в админке это
[image: ебаная дичь]
Сносить родительскую и ставить через админку - тоже пробовал, не помогло. Писал название в так же как и в админке - не помогло. Подскажите где ошибка?

Comment: Точку с запятой уберите из Template:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точки с запятой поубирайте! У вас названия иначе не совпадут.